# What function can I use to fit through the points (0,1), (13,0) and (p,q)?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, exponential-function

I'm trying to find a function that will go through $(0,1)$, $(13,0)$, with another point in between, say at $(6,p)$ where $0\le p\le 1$, that I can vary up and down to make the curve similar to a straight line, or as steep as possible when x is near 0.

Isn't it just a general exponential function?

I'm trying to find a function that enables me to 'flex' the curve as described above, by modifying only one variable.  I'm sure I saw a function like that once, but maybe I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1):

An exponential function won't work unless you add in a constant term, because exponential functions are never $0$.

With three points, the simplest choice for fitting would be a *quadratic function*, but there are lots of other possibilities. Which one you use should depend on some knowledge about where your function is supposed to *represent* -- but in the absence of such information I'd just go with the polynomial.

Comment: I'm trying to find a function that enables me to 'flex' the curve as described above, by modifying only one variable.  I'm fairly certain something like y=ae^(-bx)+c will work, with two of those being constants, x a variable, and the other the one I can move around to adjust the curve.  I just can't remember which is which.